# Can't mount Windows 8.1 storage drive. Partition type is random hex

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, windows-8, data-recovery

I had windows 8.1 installed on a SSD drive, and I had a separate 2TB internal HDD where I stored all of my documents. The windows 8.1 installation died on me and refused to boot, so I decided to try Ubuntu. The SSD drive has been formatted and Ubuntu has been installed in its place. I would like to recover my documents off of the 2TB drive, but every time I try to mount the drive it says you must specify the file system type. As far as I know there isn't anything wrong with the drive, and I can view the drive in the Disks utility. The only thing that seems strange is that the partition type is shown as some very long hex value. Has anyone run into this problem before and how do I go about mounting this drive so I can get my files off of it?

I was going to have a nice picture of the Disks utility showing the drive information, but apparently you need at least 10 reputation to post images. I suppose the most significant part of the picture is that it shows that the disk is OK, and the partition type is shown as e75caf8f-f680-4cee-afa3-b001e56efc2d. The partitioning is GUID Partition Table. The contents are unknown.

*UPDATE* My adventures in Ubuntu didn't last that long. I was using 14.04.2 I think? I did install GParted and inside of that utility it did give a little more detail in a less cryptic fashion. It just said that the file system type was unknown along with several other things being unknown. I switched to Ubuntu to see if things would be any smoother, but unfortunately it actually ended up being more unstable than it was in Windows. I didn't spend too much time trying to debug the issue in Ubuntu because of this and just went back to Windows. Ultimately my stability issue was because of the wrong video drivers (I have an XFX R7 260X video card). perhaps I could have found stable drivers for Ubuntu, but at least for my set up the default drivers in Ubuntu were even more unstable than the default drivers in Windows. Once back in Windows I was able to see my drive again, so ultimately I think the issue was that the utilities I was using could not recognize the drive because it was set up in Windows. In case anyone else is having this problem, I had set up the drive in Windows as a "Storage pool" (read software RAID) even though it was just a single drive. The partioning was GPT?, but it definitely was not any standard type of file system like FAT32 or NTFS. If I go back to Ubuntu, and for anyone else thinking about it, make sure to format your drives as FAT32 or NTFS so that it will be visible in both systems because apparently the "Storage Pool" format is not visible at least with the basic utilities that come with Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output of `gparted --list` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...